# Why do the number of return variables in this code make different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The result I get is very bizarre. Far from what I expected

When I give the first function two or multiple returning strings, 
for example - "More organized code", "Being a nerd"

it shows the result I expected which is - "More organized code is a benefit of functions", "Being a nerd is a benefit of functions"

However, when I but just one string "More organized code" as shown in the code I pasted, it shows a different result

*Also in the third function - for benefit in list_benefits():
how can you even use the term 'benefit' because it's not even defined!

**Here is the code:

```
def list_benefits():
    return "More organized code"

def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!"%(benefit)


def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    for benefit in list_benefits():
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

[image: This is the result I get from the code which I don't understand]

I should be getting "More organized code is a benefit of functions!"
why am I getting this result?

Comment: `list_benefits()` function returns a string object. iteration over a string object yields its characters.

Comment: `benefit` *is* defined, it's the loop variable.

Comment: Appreciate for your time and answer guys im just a noob who started python 5days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `print(build_sentence(benefit))` in the for loop of `name_the_benefits_of_functions` with `benefit="More organized code"`, you are actually iterating on the characters, hence you see individual characters being printed, which essentially means the following is being run

```
def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s"%(benefit)


def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    for benefit in 'More organized code':
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

And the output is

```
M
o
r
e

o
r
g
a
n
i
z
e
d

c
o
d
e
```

To get rid of this behaviour, you need to ensure that you return a list of strings, if you want to use more than one strings, instead of a single string, which caused the iteration on, also I would get rid of `build_sentence` and `list_benefits` functions since we can easily do without them. So the code will look it

```
#List of benefits as list of strings
list_benefits = ["More organized code", "Being a nerd"]

#Function to print the strings
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    for benefit in list_benefits:
        print("%s is a benefit of functions!"%(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

And the output will look like

```
More organized code is a benefit of functions!
Being a nerd is a benefit of functions!
```

Answer (score 2):

Check what happens when iterating over a string:

```
>>> for l in list_benefits():
...     print(l)
... 
M
o
r
e

o
r
g
a
n
i
z
e
d

c
o
d
e
```

So, you are printing each of the letter in `"More organized code"`, as the first letter (the formated one) in the call to `build_sentence`

If you want the actual `"More organized code is a benefit of functions!"` output you should simply return an iterable from `list_benefits`:

```
def list_benefits():
    return ["More organized code"]

def build_sentence(benefit):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!"%(benefit)


def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    for benefit in list_benefits():
        print(build_sentence(benefit))

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```